# Saving User Options in c#

Tags: c#

I watched some tutorials and none of them didn't work... I even changed my Visual Studio from 2015 in 2010, nothing works...

That's the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WindowsFormsApplication3.Properties.Settings.Default.label = label1.Text;
    WindowsFormsApplication3.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    label1.Text = WindowsFormsApplication3.Properties.Settings.Default.label;
}
```

In label1 Application Settings I made a setting with:

name: label ; Type: String ; Scope: User ; Value: Seen ;

When I press the Button in the program absolutely nothing is happening :|

Comment: The `Form1_Load` happens before the `button1_Click` event, so the label won't be updated until the form is reloaded. And unless you change the text in `label1` you are not actually making any changes in the first place.

Comment: How are you trying to save the Options?

Comment: Labels are non editable controls, so how are you changing the value of the label before saving the new value?

Comment: Thank you very much, now it's working. It's the same thing if I try to do this with a checkbox?

Comment: _It's the same thing if I try to do this with a checkbox?_ You can put a bool in the settings file and do the same thing as you did with the label.

Comment: I did it, thank you for everything!

Answer (score 0):

I think your expectations may be a little wrong on what is supposed to happen

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.Label = label1.Text + "!";//change the value
        WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); //save the change
        WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.Reload(); //instruct the form to reload the settings from the file
        label1.Text = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.Label; //update the label text to show the change
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.Label; // set the initial value
    }
```

this works fine